# how to convert hex to decimal in sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, hex, decimal

I'm trying to get data based on a specific field (int) with a hex "input"

```
select *
from table
where id = to_base(7F1943EE,10)
```

how can I convert 7F1943EE to decimal value?

Answer (score 3):

You want [`conv()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv);

```
SELECT conv('7F1943EE', 16, 10);
```